# PowerShell xml.Save does not save the file on the same path in IntelliJ

Tags: xml, powershell, intellij-idea, relative-path, powershell-5.1

I have created a simple powershell script (**replacer.ps1**), which:

1. Reads a xml file
2. Changes one of the attributes
3. Saves file

The code of **replacer.ps1** is as follows:

```
function ReplaceElemInXml
{
    param ([string]$xmlFilePath)
    [xml]$xmlContent = Get-Content -Path $xmlFilePath
    $element = $xmlContent.SelectSingleNode("//aa")
    $element.SetAttribute("checksum", "newAttributeValue")
    $xmlContent.Save($xmlFilePath)
    Write-Output "Attribute updated successfully for file: $xmlFilePath "
}

ReplaceElemInXml -xmlFilePath "test.xml"
```

the structure of my folder is:

[image]

After I run the code from the commandline in IntelliJ:

```
> attributeReplacer\childFolder\onemoreChildFolder> .\replacer.ps1
```

The output says:

```
Attribute updated successfully for file: test.xml
```

But the original test.xml file is not being updated, instead a new test.xml file is being created in the root folder of IntelliJ project:

[image]

How can I overwrite the file in the current folder?

Comment: Does it work if you create [Shell Script](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/shell-scripts.html#shell-scripts-configurations) run/debug configuration and configure `Working directory` path the same as the location of you script?

Comment: @EgorKlepikov I would like to run it simply from commandline, not as an IntelliJ "run".

Comment: Powershell runspaces have a “current directory” which is independent from the process “working directory” (which is what dotnet methods use), so your *relative* file path “test.xml” is being resolved relative to *different* root folders in ```Get-Content``` and ```$xmlContent.Save``` - see https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/2626 for some background…

Comment: @mclayton I see, but in that case what is the solution for my issue?

Comment: Given that the file path already exists, you can use ```Convert-Path``` to turn the (powershell) relative path into a fully qualified filesystem path and pass that to dotnet methods instead...